# MVVMCross: UIButton Not Binding (Programmatically)

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.ios, uibutton, mvvmcross

Currently having an annoying issue of my UIButton not being Bound to the ViewModel. When clicking on the Button the ViewModel's IMVXCommand is not called. The button shows up but doesn't recognize the Touch Event. The Truly weird thing is if I was to create the LoginButton using the Interface Builder the below code works.

The following is sample code:

```
[Register("LoginView")]
public class LoginView : MvxView
{
    UIBUtton loginButton;

    public LoginView(IntPtr handler) : base(handler)
    {
    }

    public LoginView(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        this.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame;
        init();
    }

    init()
    {
      CreateView();
    }

    CreateView()
    {
      loginButton = new UIButton(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 193, 300, 30))
        {
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(15, UIFontWeight.Medium),
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
        };
      AddSubView(loginButton);
      var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
      set.Bind(loginButton).To(vm => vm.ClickCommand);
      set.Apply();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    public AuthenticationViewModel() : base()
    {
    }

        public IMvxCommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(HandleClick);
        }
    }

    public void HandleClick()
    {
        //This never gets called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW, so no joke 5 minutes after I posted this I realized I had forgotten to set the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel.

Literally, this line of code fixes the problem.

```
this.DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
```

Add that into the Init method and all is well

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Comment: I think the right solution is to pass the Datacontext of the container MvxViewController to LoginView. This way both views will have the same instance of the LoginViewModel